# Change woocommerce booking calendar positions

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-bookings

How I can swap booking calendar with person types?

So calendar would be upper and person type fields are under calendar

At the moment it is like this:
[image: booking]

Answer (score 0):

hi you can move its position to top with CSS like this
add CSS for calender area

```
    fieldset {
 position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

set booking form  position

```
position: relative;
```

and give first input field margin-top equal to the calendar like eg: margin:top:300px;

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use add ons instead of person types, to have those option, add ons automatically appear below the calendar